# Samsung Smart TV Samsung IME for text input

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, on-screen-keyboard

I am trying to implement IME in my web app. (using this [tutorial](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/?FolderName=tut00119&FileName=index.html)).
Reading UX Guideline on Samsung developer Forum here:
[UX Guideline](http://www.samsungdforum.com/UxGuide/2014/05_text_input.html#ux-02)

I just saw, that there is also another type of Samsung IME on-screen keyboard.

Does anybody know, how do I implement this kind of on-screen keyboard shown in ux-guideline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as you say there is 2 type of IME.
12key and qwerty

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00006/IME_Module.html
http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/?FolderName=tut00049&FileName=index.html

Check them

```
imeobj.setKeySetFunc('qwerty');
imeobj.setKeySetFunc('12key');
```

can change IME mode.